# Why is the parameter for my procedure getting a 'not a function' error?

Tags: function, syntax, compiler-errors, functional-programming, scheme

I am going through the book *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programming*, which uses Scheme, and I just got through a portion on recursion.  I wrote a program for exercise 1.11:

*A function f is defined by the rule that f(n) = n if n<3 and f(n) = f(n - 1) + 2f(n - 2) + 3f(n - 3) if n> 3. Write a procedure that computes f by means of a recursive process. Write a procedure that computes f by means of an iterative process.*

I wrote the code at [repl.it](https://repl.it/@Jodastt/scheme) and when I run the procdure with the input `2`, it gives me the error: `Error: 2 is not a function [fRecurse, (anon)]`.  Can somebody explain to me what this means and how I can fix it?  Why is it expecting my input to be a function?

Code:

```
(define (fRecurse n)(
(cond ((< n 3) n)
      ((>= n 3) 
        (+ (procRecurse (- n 1))
           (* 2 (f (- fRecurse 2)))
           (* 3 (f (- fRecurse 3))))))))
(fRecurse 2)
```

Comment: This is more of a syntax problem, and so I don't think that the "algorithm" tag is appropriate here.

Comment: @ElliottSmith retagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to an extra pair of parentheses before `(cond...)`. To fix the issue, we simply remove the extra pair of parentheses:

```
(define (fRecurse n)
  (cond ((< n 3) n)
      ((>= n 3) 
        (+ (fRecurse (- n 1))
           (* 2 (fRecurse (- n 2)))
           (* 3 (fRecurse (- n 3)))))))

(fRecurse 2)
```

And some additonal fixes I made to your example to make it work correctly:

- Change `f` to `fRecurse`
- Change `procRecurse` to `fRecurse`
- Change `(* 2 (f (- fRecurse 2)))` to `(* 2 (fRecurse (- n 2)))`
- Change `(* 3 (f (- fRecurse 3)))` to `(* 3 (fRecurse (- n 3)))`

See the updated [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UpbeatDarkblueCarrier)

Comment: thanks a ton, I didnt't even realize I made that many errors.